# Gephi: increase maximal zoom

Tags: social-networking, gephi

I want to use gephi to plot a huge network with ~5.500 notes. I would like to see more of the network structure, thus I use Force Atlas with a large *Repulsion Strength*. Unfortunatly, at some point when I zoom out, a mystical square appears which seem to be the limit size of gephis network-window:
[image]

Is there a way to increase that value? I would like that the graph can further expand. Surprisingly, internet search didn't help to answer this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no easy way to change the available coordinates in Gephi.

5 500 nodes is a small network for Gephi. Even with [over 200 000 nodes](https://medium.com/startup-grind/analyzing-205-718-verified-twitter-users-cf0811781ac8) Gephi has no problem with showing the structure of a network.

Some suggestions:

- Turn off the edges in the Graph window, because they obstruct the view. It looks like your graph already shows structure, but there are so many edges that you can't see it.
- Reduce the node size.
- Use the ForceAtlas2 layout algorithm, which is an improvement over ForceAtlas.
- Set a smaller scale if you hit the borders of the available coordinates.
- Try the OpenOrd layout algorithm. It is great for big networks and supports edge cutting.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in the Gephi's Facebook group I believe only I can't really locate it now. You have hit a wall here because your graph has reached the maximum/minimum coordinates that a node can take. If you think of it, it is a square and you cannot go beyond this unfortunately.

I was surprised that you are using such a large repulsion with such a small graph but then I saw that your graph is rather dense, so I imagine that you tried to pull the nodes apart. The problem is that the graph is such that you will probably not be able to get rid of the clutter.

I would try though to play with the size of the nodes using an *spline*, see [here](http://www.martingrandjean.ch/gephi-introduction/), Section 3.2, and then run again the *ForceAtlas2* or *OpenOrd* followed by *ForceAtlas2*.